# Calculating a value in $\mathbb{Z^3}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $\mathbb{Z^3}= \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \ \times \mathbb{Z}$.
Let $f(X) = X^2 + X +1 \in\mathbb{Z^3}[x]$; $1=(1,1,1)\in \mathbb Z^3$.
Let $x = (1, 0, 2) \in \mathbb{Z^3}$.
I am to find the value of $f(x)$. My answer is $(3,1,7)$. Is it correct?

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb Z\otimes\mathbb Z\otimes\mathbb Z=\mathbb Z$?

Comment: No. We define $\mathbb Z\otimes\mathbb Z\otimes\mathbb Z= \{ (a, b, c): a, b, c \in \mathbb Z \}$

Comment: That would be just $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ in my dictionary; $\otimes$ usually denotes the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product). But if that's what you mean, the answer is correct.

Comment: @Wojowu That's true. I was told on my lecture that $\otimes$ might be not the best symbol. However we're still using it. Sorry!

Comment: It should be $\oplus$ not $\otimes.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algebraic operations in a product of rings like $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ are defined componentwise. So, if $x = (1,0,2)$, then, indeed,

$$x^2+x+1 = (1^2,0^2,2^2) + (1,0,2) + (1,1,1) = (3,1,7)$$

That is, your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helped.